# How to improve Zend Lucene performance?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, full-text-search, zend-search-lucene

I am currently struggling to speed up my [Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) index. It contains about 1M documents. In some cases it takes up to 0.4 sec to search through it. It is not acceptable. I wish it could return results within 0.1 sec max.

The documentation does not contain any information about performance issues of the engine except it says the engine is well-scalable. The only thing I have learned is possibility of using `optimize()` method. This is not enough, though. Thus, I have two questions:

1. Does order of fields added to each row (document) matter (in terms of performance)?
2. Are there any additional parameters I could use to possibly speed it up? Perhaps it could be some parameter used for indexing or some server setting (more memory, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest moving to real Lucene (or Solr) for better performance.

Otherwise, try to reduce the number of fields you store and/or index. Maybe run ulimit on your webserver process to free up more memory.

Comment: What do you mean by 'real Lucene'? Its Java version? I think Zend Lucene is just the same code but rewritten in php.

Comment: Yes but that runs as a daemon/server. Things are stored in-memory. Translated code probably won't run as fast as original code.